# AS3 FLEX SOAP WSLD Argument error

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, soap, wsdl, rpc

I'm having a problem sending multiple arguments through to a web service, using the Flex RPC Soap libraries.

Code:

```
var assetOperation:AbstractOperation = new AbstractOperation();
assetOperation = fws.getOperation("registerBarcodeByString");
assetOperation.arguments = [AppID, BarCode];
var assetToken:AsyncToken = new AsyncToken();
assetToken = assetOperation.send();

trace(assetToken.message);

assetToken.addResponder(new Responder(getBarcodeResult, getBarcodeError));
```

Looking at the logs on the web service, both the AppID and BarCode are being received as the first argument placed in the array.  No matter what goes first, that item will be passed as every argument.

Imagine I'm sending [1234, 6789], the web service is receiving [1234, 1234].

I've tried placing the args in the send() method, same thing happens.  I've tried creating a temporary object which stores these args and sending that, same thing.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing the args, I had to pass through more information, in this case the exact name of each argument as expected by the web service.

So:

```
assetOperation.arguments = [{applicationLabel:AppID, barcodeString:BarCode}];
```